# How to split large json file into multiple using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, split

I have big JSON file having 4400000 records (200 MB) in NDJSON format.

**Sample Data:**

```
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"1.5.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8325021+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"243.11.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"253.11.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"39.24.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"163.24.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
```

I want to split this into 4 JSON files equally based on the number of rows using powershell.

Output: There will be 4 JSON file containing 1100000 rows each.

Could you please help how to do it using PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **NDJSON is a *line-oriented* format, *plain-text processing* will do**, so you simply need to create each file with the specified number of lines.

While a cmdlet-based pipeline solution is possible, for **performance reasons** *reading* large files in PowerShell is best handled with the **[`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement**, whereas **direct use of .NET APIs**, namely [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter), is required for efficient *writing* of files.

Note:

- This will create output files `Out_01.json` through `Out_04.json` in the current directory - adjust the name template as needed.

  - Note that if 4 chunks of `1100000` lines each do not cover *all* lines of your input file, you'll get *additional* output files (or fewer, if there are fewer input lines).
- **Character encoding notes**:

  - The *output* files will be BOM-less UTF-8 files by default, though you may specify an encoding explicitly, as noted in the source-code comments below.
  - With respect to the *input* files:

    - `switch -File` assumes *UTF-8* in the absence of a BOM in a given input file, in *both* PowerShell editions (which is surprising, because only *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (consistently) defaults to UTF-8, whereas *Windows PowerShell*'s default is usually *ANSI*), and doesn't allow you specify an input encoding explicitly.
    - If you need to control the encoding for reading the files explicitly, use the [`System.IO.File.ReadLines`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) .NET API in a `foreach` loop instead, which allows you to; e.g., to use ANSI encoding:

      ```bash
      foreach (
        $line in [IO.File]::ReadLines(
          (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $inputFile), 
          [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.AnsiCodePage)
        )
      ) {
        # ... work with $line instead of $_
      }
      ```

```bash
# This makes the Write-Verbose call below show output.
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

# Your input file path.
$inputFile = 'input.json'

# Construct a file-path template for the sequentially numbered 
# output files; e.g., "Out_01.json"
# Note: Be sure to use a *full* path, as that is required for .NET calls.
$outFilePathTemplate = Join-Path $PWD.ProviderPath 'Out_{0:00}.json'

# Set how many lines make up a chunk.
$chunkLineCount = 1100000

# Read the file lazily and save every chunk of $chunkLineCount
# lines to a new file.
$i = 0; $chunkNdx = 0
switch -File $inputFile {
  default {
    if (++$i % $chunkLineCount -eq 1) {
      # Create new chunk file.
      # Close previous file, if any.
      if (++$chunkNdx -gt 1) { $fileWriter.Dispose() }
  
      # Construct the file path for the next chunk, by
      # instantiating the path template with the next sequence number.
      $outFilePath = $outFilePathTemplate -f $chunkNdx
      Write-Verbose "Creating chunk file: $outFilePath"
  
      # Create the next chunk file
      # Note: Default encoding is BOM-less UTF-8
      #       Pass a [System.Text.Encoding] instance to change it.
      $fileWriter = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($outFilePath)
    }
    # Write the line at hand to the current chunk file.
    $fileWriter.WriteLine($_)  
  }
}
$fileWriter.Dispose() # Close the last file.
```

---

**Alternatively**, ***if* you have the Unix [`split` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) at your disposal** - by default on Unix-like platforms, installable on Windows or usable via WSL - consider its use instead: not only is such a solution more concise, but it **will perform much better**:

```bash
# Creates output files 'Out_00.json' through 'Out_03.json'

# Requires the GNU implementation of external utility `split`,
# as present on *Linux* systems and in *WSL*
# Numbering starts with 0 - use, e.g., --numeric-suffixes=1 to start with 1.
split --number=4 -d --additional-suffix=.json input.json Out_

# *macOS* equivalent: no support for long option names, and no
# support for --additional-suffix or --numeric-suffixes, so the 
# output files will have *no filename extension* and 
# numbering invariably starts from 0.
split -n 4 -d input.json Out_
# Add extension ".json" to the output files' names.
Get-Item Out_[0-9][0-9] | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '.json' }
```

Note that `--number=4` specifies the number of *output files* to create, with `split` automatically determining how many lines to put in each for even distribution.

If you do want to specify the number of *lines per output file*, use `-l 110000` (`--lines=110000`) instead.

Comment: Do you know a way to specify an encoding for `switch -File`?

Comment: @zett42, excellent question: I don't think you can, and what's worse: in Windows PowerShell, `switch -File` defaults to UTF-8(!) in the absence of a BOM, so it behaves differently than `Get-Content` there. (That default is fine in PS Core, where everything consistently uses UTF-8). Please see my update.